# How to find the source file of the javascript

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces 5.1. When I load my web page, go into the Firefox debugger and look into the javascript, I see that it has loaded some javascript (Primefaces.js.jsf to be precise) which is part of Primefaces 5.0 version. Now, I have taken care to delete all the references of 5.0. But still I get the same result.

So, my question is- when a web page is loaded, and we see the javascript files loaded, how do we know where a particular script file is being retrieved from?

P.S: I'm not the one who wrote the code to include this js. it is part of the framework. So, I have no control over where it is being accessed from. All I can do is if I know the path of the file, I can modify it to suit my needs.
I have deleted the history/cache/Temporary files and also loaded the page using Ctrl + F5. Didnt help.

Comment: What do you mean you have taken care to delete all the references of 5.0 and you still get the same result ? Do you mean the parameters in the end like `?ln=primefaces&v=5.0`

Comment: I meant I made sure to delete primefaces-5.0.jar from the lib directory under WEB-INF and verified the build path to not have any reference to primefaces-5.0.

Comment: Found out why the project was still referring to PF5.0. The primefaces-5.0.jar still co-existed with primefaces-5.1.jar in the WEB-INF/lib directory of the project residing in the glassfish directory 'glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\eclipseApps'.

Answer (score 0):

Found out why the project was still referring to PF5.0. The primefaces-5.0.jar still co-existed with primefaces-5.1.jar in the WEB-INF/lib directory of the project residing in the glassfish directory 'glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\eclipseApps'.